# Getting User authority error (_ERR_USER_AUTHORITY) on handler databean mapping in WCS

Tags: rest, wcs

I have created a REST handler which was mapped to a data bean.
And I am calling the databean using this method

```
executeConfigBasedBeanWithContext(dataBeanName, profileName, responseFormat,
                typedProperty);
```

Now, on calling this handler, I am getting the below `Exception`:

> EC_APPLICATION_EXCEPTION like The user does not have authority to
>   execute this query (_ERR_USER_AUTHORITY).

But it was working for Admin users(`wcsadmin`) without any exception. 
Below is the `REST Exception`:

> {"errors":[{"errorParameters":["com.xxxx.commerce.order.command.CodeDataBean"],"errorCode":"CWXFR0268E","errorKey":"NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_QUERY","errorMessage":"CWXFR0268E:
>   You are not authorized to execute query: GET
>   https://localhost/wcs/resources/store/10154/codedata"}]}

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Per the IBM documentation

> If you are using remote binding through REST service calls, and the
>   data bean does not implement the Delegator interface, only a Site
>   Administrator can run the service call by default. This can be
>   customized by overriding the isSiteResource(DataBean) method of the
>   REST Resource Handler class.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.webservices.doc/concepts/cwvrestsecurityauth.htm?lang=en